# SSIS Transposing Header Information With Excel Load

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, bus

I've tried searching but most of the excel loads dealing with header information ask about ignoring them instead of loading them.

I'm working on a project, and have 7 lines of header information I would like loaded into my database table, it looks like this:

[image: header]

Using OpenRowset I load only A3:D13, when I check the Columns section of the Excel Source I only see these columns:

[image: columns]

I needed to add a column for load date so I've added a derived column into my data flow, after which it looks like this:

[image: derived]

Finally I add the DB destination and map out the columns, but as you can see I only have 4 input columns to my 7 columns in my table:

[image]

and after trying to load the file into my table I get this mess:

[image]

I'm thinking it's got something to do with how the header is formatted, instead of the normal heading then data directly below it, it's set up as heading then data adjacent to the heading.

Any ideas on what I can do to load this information correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are rows, not columns.

Comment: @JacobH Do I have to unpivot/pivot them inside ssis to change them from rows to columns then?

Comment: I think that makes the most sense. Otherwise I think you will have to do something like a for each loop to query each "column" individually. Maybe someone else has a better idea though.

Comment: You have some hidden rows that you might want to deal with before unpivoting.

Comment: @KeithL I think all rows are unhidden or Is there any other way to unhide it other than right-clicking the excel sheet and selecting unhide? Because the option is grayed out.

Comment: hidden rows will be in your data flow. ie rows 5,7,9,11

Comment: @KeithL Ahh, I see it now, in my excel sheet whenever I search for those rows, nothing shows up though.  Only a black line is highlighted in-between the rows that are visible.  How would I go about making those rows visible in my data flow?

Comment: So before you unpivot, I would conditionally split out null rows.

Comment: this is a lot of work for one record. could you possibly get a better source?

Comment: @KeithL Unfortunately, no I'd be getting these reports every 5 months.